# Ruby OCI.DLL Load Error

Tags: ruby, oracle

I'm new to Ruby, and I'm having problems with the oci8 gem for oracle. I installed the gem correctly then downloaded the instant client from the oracle page for 64 bit windows and I'm getting the following error:

> n `require': OCI.DLL: 193(%1 no es una aplicaci�n Win32 v�lida.  ) (LoadError)

The thing is that I downloaded the 64 bit version from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html and added the path to where I decompressed the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first you must install instantclient followed by oci8 gem, otherwise oci8 will not be available.

Uninstall oci8 gem and reinstall it again

Follow this article. I was having the same issue

http://www.shanison.com/2010/08/29/use-oracle-connection-for-ruby-on-rails-2-2-2/

Also add the instant client path to the environment variables ‘Path’(folder containing OCI.dll ).